# COM error while reconnecting to UIA app using Pywinauto through RPyC

Tags: python, pywinauto, rpyc

I have connected to a windows app using pywinauto like below,

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.call("start shell:AppsFolder\myapp!App", shell=True)

from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application(backend="uia")
my_app = app.connect(title="myapp", class_name="ApplicationFrameWindow")
```

but this is through Python's RPyC connection.

For the first time, this code works fine but if I run my script again using same RPyC connection, I see the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 944, in connect
self.process = findwindows.find_element(**kwargs).process_id
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 197, in find_elements
cache_enable=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py", line 272, in children
return self._get_elements(IUIA().tree_scope["children"], cond, cache_enable)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_element_info.py", line 261, in _get_elements
ptrs_array = self._element.FindAll(tree_scope, cond)
COMError: (-2147024809, 'The parameter is incorrect.', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

If I close existing RPyC connection and open another session then the above code works fine. I could not able to figure out why I see this error. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like a known bug. Can you try the latest master branch?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, I tried [pywinauto-0.6.3](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/releases/download/0.6.3/pywinauto-0.6.3.zip). I still see the same issue

Comment: 0.6.3 is not the same as latest master branch.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, Awesome, it's working with master branch. Thanks. You can add it as an answer, I will upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s a known issue already fixed in master branch. Will be released soon as pywinauto==0.6.4.